# Parent Armature not triggering constraint between Child Bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, parent, bone.constraints

Pretty new to animation and armatures, I was following along with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2shn1LpcNE) to rig my wheel up to be used as the player character in a Unity game. The video was made with a much earlier version of blender, whereas I'm on 3.4.1

So, basically I've got three armatures/bones and I'm trying to make a wheel rotate as it moves along the X axis. One bone (the "Rotate Bone") is pointing up the Y axis, and is the parent of the whole wheel mesh hierarchy, so its responsible for rotating the wheel. The Rotate Bone has a bone constraint whose target is another bone, which I've dubbed the Trajectory Bone, and whose function is to convert the Trajectory Bone's movement along the X axis (a.k.a. the bone's Y axis) into rotation of the Rotate Bone. The third bone— the Control Bone—is the parent (via the "Bone" option in the parenting context menu) of the other two bones, which is supposed to tie the Trajectory Bone's movement through space with the actual wheel's displacement.

Moving the Trajectory Bone alone in pose mode correctly triggers the constraint and rotates the wheel, but for some reason, moving the parental Control Bone does not. The video has the constraint's Target/Owner space set to "Local with Parent" and "Local" respectively, but I've tried that configuration plus almost every one with no success. Setting them to "World Space" does make the Control Bone trigger the constraint, but only when moving along the Y axis rather than the X (and changing the Trajectory Bone's Location mapping from Y to X just makes the whole constraint non-functional).

How do I make the Control Bone move both the Trajectory Bone and the Rotate Bone/Wheel in such a way that it triggers the constraint between the Traj Bone and Rotate Bone?

(Also, I realize the video has a fourth bone that is pointing up the Z axis that is parenting the Rotate Bone, but this seems useless to me and indeed, including it in my rig had no effect on the problem.)

Screenshot kind of outlines everything; the parental hierarchy, the constraint, and the bones.
[image: Screenshot of my setup]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file so that we can test it? https://blend-exchange.com/